# Typescript 1.8 lib.d.ts missing autoIncrement property on IDBObjectStore Interface?

Tags: typescript, indexeddb

If I look at the following pages for specification, clearly there is a specified property (read only) on IDBObjectStore called "autoIncrement":

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore/autoIncrement

However, when attempting to read that property from inside Visual Studio 2015, or attempting to compile with the Typescript compiler, this property is marked for error:

```
// Excerpted from the code I am writing to manage our IndexedDB Schemas.
interface ISchemaForIndex {
    keyPath: string;
    name: string;
    unique: boolean;
    multiEntry: boolean;
}

interface ISchemaForObjectStore {
    clearStoreOnUpgradeBeforeVersion: number;
    name: string;
    keyPath: string;
    autoIncrement: boolean;
    indexes: ISchemaForIndex[];
}

function getOrCreateOrReCreateStore(upgradeDb: IDBDatabase, transaction: IDBTransaction, oldVersion: number, schemaObjectStore: ISchemaForObjectStore) {

    if (_.contains(upgradeDb.objectStoreNames, schemaObjectStore.name)) {
        if (oldVersion >= schemaObjectStore.clearStoreOnUpgradeBeforeVersion) {
            const objectStore = transaction.objectStore(schemaObjectStore.name);
            if (objectStore.keyPath === schemaObjectStore.keyPath &&

                // NEXT LINE HAS ERROR ON ATTEMPT TO READ autoIncrement PROPERTY FROM objectStore
                objectStore.autoIncrement === schemaObjectStore.autoIncrement) {

                return objectStore;
            }
        }
        upgradeDb.deleteObjectStore(schemaObjectStore.name);
    }
    return upgradeDb.createObjectStore(schemaObjectStore.name,
    { keyPath: schemaObjectStore.keyPath, autoIncrement: schemaObjectStore.autoIncrement });
}
```

It appears that the interface in question is defined in the lib.d.ts, found in my system in the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8 .

That file simply seems to be missing the property in question.  Here is the interface definition from that file:

```
// Excerpt from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8\lib.d.ts
interface IDBObjectStore {
    indexNames: DOMStringList;
    keyPath: string;
    name: string;
    transaction: IDBTransaction;
    add(value: any, key?: any): IDBRequest;
    clear(): IDBRequest;
    count(key?: any): IDBRequest;
    createIndex(name: string, keyPath: string | string[], optionalParameters?: IDBIndexParameters): IDBIndex;
    delete(key: any): IDBRequest;
    deleteIndex(indexName: string): void;
    get(key: any): IDBRequest;
    index(name: string): IDBIndex;
    openCursor(range?: any, direction?: string): IDBRequest;
    put(value: any, key?: any): IDBRequest;
}
```

The property autoIncrement is nowhere to be found.

Interestingly enough, in that same file, the property does exist (optionally) on the IDBObjectStoreParameters interface.

Any insights on what this problem is, and what a healthy workaround might be?  I'm a bit baffled.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try creating a supplementary type definition (i.e. `foo.d.ts`) file inside your TS project, link it (i.e. `/// <reference path="foo.d.ts" />`) and define the `autoIncrement` property in another `interface IDBObjectStore` definition. TypeScript should merge the interfaces together and that should hopefully get rid of that property error (cf. [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the interface at runtime, like @miqid suggested. I usually put a `lib.d.ts` in the src folder, with something like this:

```
declare module IDBObjectStore {
    const autoIncrement: any;
}
```

I use this for extending the CodeMirror typedefs for a property my defs are missing. Not sure if your d.ts is defined in the same fashion as mine, but there's plenty on Google (and SO) on extending typescript interfaces.

Comment: Cool, thanks.  Coming to Typescript fairly recently, I had been unaware that it was common for standard typedefs to be missing elements.  Not sure whether this will be "our answer" or whether we will follow the suggestion by @morphatic below.... one of these two will be marked "the answer" soon!

Comment: Consensus in our dev team is to stop using the typings utility and to put lib.d.ts under source code control.  Thanks.

Comment: If you're suggesting somehow just gobbing all typedefs into that one file, I would strongly recommend against that. Having to maintain that information will be a heavy stone to carry forward. If the issue is for instance build server network access, either just check the typings folder into src, or setup an npm mirror (lots of info on how to do this). Having a lib.d.ts file is something I mostly find good for either getting over a hurdle right now, or for minor patches, not for wholesale definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to upgrade your definitions. You can see that the `autoIncrement` property is defined in [the Typescript repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts#L425). If you look at the commit history, [it was added on 2016-02-23](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/commit/7ae6fcd65ef48ef33f62883e7bd64a3634c15333#diff-0abb36c63a4c22194c1931b03ac33053).

Comment: Hmmmm.  Interesting.  I just upgraded to Typescript 1.8 through visual studio a couple of days ago, and would have imagined I would get the latest from Microsoft.  I guess not.  Thanks.  I'm coming to Typescript fairly recently, and am not so familiar with this kind of missing element from Typedef.  (Not frequent in .NET!)  Not sure whether our team will use your answer or @Svend as "the answer", but one of them will be marked "the answer" in the next couple of days.  Thanks.